# Boost array Initialization in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

I need to declare a boost::array. I did it as `boost::array<char, 116> buf;`
is there a possibility that I can declare with the size stored as a constant that is initialized from property file. something like `boost::array<char, BUFFER_SIZE> buf;`

Any Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you want a dynamically sizable array, use a `std::vector`

Reason for No is that the template parameter cannot be provided at run time (caveat: current standard)

Answer (score 3):

If it's a constant available at compile-time, (meaning you `#include`d your property file or something) then yes.

```
int const BUFFER_SIZE = 116;
boost::array<char, BUFFER_SIZE> buf;
```

is valid. If it isn't available at compile-time, then no.